# If Arsenal wins the 2019 UEFA Europa League final, which teams will represent England in the Champions League next year?

Tags: football, uefa, champions-league, qualifying, europa-league

Since all other teams in the UEFA finals except Arsenal have been qualified for the Champions League next year.
Will Arsenal (if they win the UEFA Europa League final) replace Tottenham or Chelsea for a place in the Champions League next year or will there (in that case) instead be five English teams in the Champions League next year?

```
    Premier League 2018-19 Final Standing
    1 Man City      Champions League
    2 Liverpool     Champions League
    3 Chelsea       Champions League
    4 Tottenham     Champions League
    5 Arsenal       Europa League
    6 Man United    Europa League Qualifying
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The English Premier League is guaranteed at least four, and may earn a total of five, places at the next Champions League group stage.

They are assigned in the following priority order.

1. The previous Champions League winner
2. The previous Europa League winner
3. The first-place team in the Premier League
4. The second-place team in the Premier League
5. The third-place team in the Premier League
6. The fourth-place team in the Premier League

If these are all six distinct teams, the last team in order is dropped to the next Europa League group stage, and there are additional flow-on effects depending on the winners of the English Football League and the FA Cup, and whether they are placed in the top of the Premier League.